# remove java script from html using sed

Tags: sed, find

I am trying to remove java script tags for google_ad_client from php/html files using find , sed but it doesn't work

For example, if the script tags contain something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7800000000";
/* my_navbar */
google_ad_slot = "4996537872";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
```

so i use the following command to remove it

```
find . -type f -name '*.php*' -print0 | xargs sed -i '/<script type="text\/javascript">/,/<\/script>/g'
```

this work but it delete me all java script in side my html files

Comment: Use a DOM Parser for that. `sed` is the wrong tool for that.

Comment: If you are trying to recover from a malware incident, the proper response is to revert to uninfected versions from version control or known-good backups.

Answer (score 0):

**using sed like**

```
sed  -r  ':loop;$!{N;b loop};{s~<script type="text\/javascript">[^>]+google_ad_client =[^<]+</script>~~g}'
```

**example**

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-7800000000";
/* my_navbar */
google_ad_slot = "4996537872";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
something here
//-->
</script>
```

**results**

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
something here
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: guys I've tried all what's you had mentions ..but one work with me .. anyhow .. I've upload one php file which contain for the same ,, [from here](http://www.q8mazad.com/old/test.php)